# How can I change the default domain in an OTRS installation?

Tags: configuration, turnkey-linux, otrs

I used a [turnkeylinux.org](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/otrs) otrs installation and I'm trying to configure the default domain of 'yourhost.example.com'.  I tried the following:

```
sed -ri 's/yourhost.example.com/mydomain.com/' /usr/share/otrs/Kernel/Config/Defaults.pm
sudo shutdown -r now
```

The next time I logged and tried to create a user, the default domain was still there.

***How can I change default doamin in an OTRS installation?***

Comment: Maybe there's a config.pm file to modify ? Did you try greping in all the files (grep -r "yourhost" /usr/share/otrs/Kernel/Config/).

Comment: Well I suppose I could do: `find /usr/share/otrs/ -type f -exec sed -ri 's/yourhost.example.com/mydomain.com/' {} \;`  ... buuuut I was hoping someone could point me to how to do it through the interface (as a best practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should modify `/etc/otrs/Kernel/Config.pm` - the guys at turnkeylinux are using the default Debian OTRS package.

Please read `/usr/share/doc/otrs2/README.Debian` for instructions on how to make the permissions a little less paranoid so you can leverage the Package Manager and the SysConfig, two powerful OTRS features.

So are you using the new Turnkey images based on Ubuntu Lucid? Which means you have OTRS 2.4.7?

--
Mike.

Comment: The Turnkey distro I'm using is based on Hardy Heron.

Comment: Which means you're testing out a real old version of OTRS: 2.2.x or so. Please just get the latest OTRS version from http://otrs.org/download instead.

Comment: That's your solution: upgrade?